# NSAttributedString linkTextAttributes

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I created a link within a NSAttributedString. When the link is clicked it is handled with:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool
```

The issue I'm having is when i click on the link, I usually get the contextual menu to **Select | Select All**

I have to hold on the link to trigger the shouldInteractWithURL function.

I've tried a few different approaches to prevent this from happening but I cannot seem to find a good solution. Is it possible to have the link prevent the select menu?

Comment: What are the property of your UITextView? Selectable? Editable?

Comment: They are both and need to be both since we need to select/edit text in the textview.

Comment: No. From the documentation of that method: `Important:
Links in text views are interactive only if the text view is selectable but noneditable. That is, if the value of the UITextViewisSelectable property is true and the isEditable property is false.`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1649337-textview